# How to finish up this first order differential equation?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

$$x^2y'-5xy = x^8\sin x, x>0$$

NOW WITH EDITS!

I understand the steps involved in solving this problem.

Step one is to get to the form:

$$y'+p(x)y=q(x)$$
So I divide by $x^2$ to get
$$y' - (5/x)y = x^6\sin x$$
Now I know $p(x) = -5/x$
so $$\mu(x) = e^{\int\frac{-5}{x}dx}$$
$$\mu(x) = e^{-5lnx}$$
$$\mu(x) = x^{-5}$$
solving we have $$\mu(x)y=\int{q(x)\mu(x)}$$

this is where I'm stuck. I get to $$y = \frac{\int{xsinxdx}}{x^{-5}}$$

but can't simplify. I probably have to do Integration by Parts but I'm stuck. I hope that me typing out all these details go to show that I really have put work into this problem but I'm very stuck. If someone wouldn't mind giving me a detailed explanation of what I'm missing I would greatly appreciate it.

EDIT **

it's solved! it comes out to $$Cx^5+x^6(-cosx)+x^5(sinx)$$

thanks for all of the help!

Comment: I would say $\quad e^{5lnx} = x^5$

Comment: @georg, how can I do integration by parts of $\int{x^{11}sinx}$? I'm stuck in a loop of integrating by parts over and over as the x exponent goes down by one. what am i missing?

Comment: [https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwia-vLD4sDKAhVnmoMKHU8yAxcQFggcMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fpages.pacificcoast.net%2F~cazelais%2F187%2Ftabular.pdf&usg=AFQjCNFY9vIClCtyiwdCAvYjYUjpnzsZzg&sig2=eD0ROhmSPGmZdEWwhbka0w][1]  Sometimes doing the integration by parts using a table makes it less confusing. 


  [1]: http://

Comment: You will have 11+2=13 rows.

Comment: Check again the integrating factor. You should get to $(y(x)/x^5)'=x\sin x$.

Comment: I didn't even check his work...Yep it looks like OP chose the wrong integrating factor. You excluded the negative in front of 5/x.